How can I add an ancilla qubit for decompose operation (MultiControlledX) in Pennylane?
I'm trying to make a quantum circuit for a uniform quantum state. Below is the code that constructs the circuit, which works well on the 'default.qubit' device. However, when I try to run this code on real hardware (IBM-Kyoto), I get the following error message:
ValueError: At least one work wire is required to decompose operation: MultiControlledX
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
From the error message, I understand that I need to add an ancilla qubit for decomposing the CCCNOT gate into CNOT gates. How can I modify my code to include ancilla qubits for this purpose?
Quantum Circuit code to run it in IBM hardware
I have add an additional wire(qubit) to the circuit. However when I plot the circuit the additional wire did not appear. So I add an Identity gate to that wire and plotted again. The additional wire appeared to the plot. However this did not solve the problemCircuit Code with additional wire and Identity matrix applied
The Circuit Code:
def uqs_ibm(nq: int, shots: int):
dev = qml.device('qiskit.ibmq', wires=nq+2, shots=shots, backend='ibm_kyoto', ibmqx_token="XXX")
@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit():
    qml.RY(theta_1 * 2, wires=0)
    
    for i in range(1, nq):  # Start from 1 since control is 0
        qml.ctrl(qml.Hadamard(i), (0))

    qml.ctrl(qml.RY, control=(0), control_values=(1))(theta_1, wires=1)
    
    
    for i in range(2, nq):
        qml.ctrl(qml.Hadamard(i), control=(0, 1), control_values=(0, 1))
        
    qml.ctrl(qml.RY, control=(0, 1), control_values=(0, 0))(theta_2, wires=2)
    
    qml.ctrl(qml.Hadamard, control=(0, 1, 2), control_values=(0, 0, 1), work_wires=5)(wires=3)
    qml.ctrl(qml.Hadamard, control=(0, 1, 2), control_values=(0, 0, 1), work_wires=6)(wires=4)
    
    return qml.probs(wires=range(nq))  # Return probabilities for all qubits

return circuit


I edited. Thank you for your comment.
